# Firebase listener on changes in currentUser properties

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to dismiss a ViewController based on changes in the Firebase currentUser parameter isEmailVerified. Basically, if the user logs in to the app and hasn't verified her email, this VC will be presented and my plan is to have it stay there until she verifies it, in which case Firebase automatically sets isEmailVerified to true and the VC should be dismissed. So far I have attached a listener to recognize changes in the currentUser in but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create listener

    let _ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in

        if user?.isEmailVerified == true {
            self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:emailTxt.text
                           password:pwdStr
                         completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {

                             if(error == nil){
                                 if (user.isEmailVerified) {
          //  present different VC
           // if user is not isEmailVerified  is not true show alert to user 
                please verify email in order to proceed

               }
                } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                                         // dismiss view
                 }];
```

Here you can see what state user is with email verification and depending show the View Controller or do nothing

Otherwise after above method use a timer method inside else condition of email verification to fire below method and check user verified email or not

```
func checkIfTheEmailIsVerified(){

FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.reload(completion: { (err) in
    if err == nil{

        if FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.isEmailVerified{

     // Your code
        } else {

            print("It aint verified yet")

        }
    } else {

        print(err?.localizedDescription)

    }
})

}
```